# javascript eval issue

Tags: javascript

I have a function that is parsing xml which contains javascript function calls.  An example of this is:

```
eval(getElementText(PropValue[0])); 

getElementText(PropValue[0] = top.hidePopWin()
```

I have followed this call up to the hidePopWin function and watched it complete from the top of the function to the bottom of the function.

Everything looks in order however I get this pesky error in Firefox: ***top is null***
As you have probably guessed hidePopWin closes the popup window that is currently displayed.

So, `hidePopWin` is called and it goes through just fine (in fact the popup does in fact close), but after that is the problem.  It doesn't go to the next step.  I get the top is null message in Firefox (firebug) and it just stops.

The only other thing I need to mention is that this whole process starts on a double click event (legacy code).  There is also a single click event that fires as well.  At first I thought maybe that was the issue, however, I took out the reference to the onclick event and I still get the same message.

So I'm thinking that it has something to do with the [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) statement.  Just for more information I am placing a `console.log("1")` above the [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) statement and a `console.log("2")` below the [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval).  The "1" prints, the "2" does not.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what might be the issue?

**Update:**

```
 if(getElementText(PropValue[0]) == "top.hidePopWin();"){
      console.log('here');
      top.hidePopWin();
      console.log('end');
 }else{
      console.log(getElementText(PropValue[0]));
       eval(getElementText(PropValue[0]));
 }
```

OK I tried the above...  I see the "here" statement, but it still says **top is null**.  The "end" statement never prints.  When I click on the top is null in FF it highlights the eval statement???  So I don't know what the heck is going on.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are using `eval`?

Comment: Well this code parses an XML file and inside the node contains a CDATA which then contains the function call.  I believe the eval is the only way to actually process the function call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK...  This may not be the best way to go, but I did finally get it to work.  Per the suggestion to change the code to run top.hidePopWin().  I tried those suggestions however I was still getting the ***top is null issue.***

In desperation I took out the "top." and now it works.  So I'm guessing there was not a "top" variable (wierd notation in my opinion).

So now I'm capturing if the string is equaling "top.hidePopWin()" and then instead of calling the eval I'm just calling the function hidePopWin();

Seems to work.  Let me know if there is another way of going about this.

Answer (score 2):

no, but could you change the code to directly execute the code outside eval and test?

So, change, eval(getElementText(PropValue[0])); 
 to 
 top.hidePopWin();

see if you get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

is 'top' visible in that scope if you breakpoint in FF (on the console.log('here') line?  It's sounding like there is no such variable (I don't know why the popup closes though).